# Adobe DTM: Fire One Event Rule For Multiple Buttons With Unique Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe

Sorry if this has been answered. I think look pretty thoroughly and couldn't find exactly what I needed.

Question: How do I set one event rule to fire a separate eVar for multiple buttons on a page?

Background: I'm trying to create one event rule to fire on all 'buy now'-type buttons on a page that's populated by a third party API (I don't have access to the API and probably won't get it, so forget that). See code below for an idea of how every button is coded.

```html
<button class="ui button secondary shop-now-btn column" ng-click="$ctrl.openProduct($ctrl.product.purchaseLink, $ctrl.product.productName); $event.stopPropagation();" data-product="123456">Shop Now
      </button>
```

The only unique identifier each button has is this attribute:

```html
data-product="123456"
```

I know how to make the event rule fire on all the buttons by using that identifier, what I can't figure out is how to make the rule push a different value to one of the evars I'm tracking.

I'm familiar with the %this.whatever% but it doesn't seem to work when you're trying to fire on multiple buttons with unique identifiers.

I think I have to create some custom code but I'm not sure where to begin. I'm a bit of a noob to this.

PLEASE HELP AND THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from this quite unclear question is that you wish to bind an event handler to "Buy now" buttons... And that they all have a `data-product` attribute.

You could do this:

```
$(document).on("click", "[data-product]" function(){
  // Do something.
});
```